# Intranet page loading slow

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, performance

In the past, I have added 5 WebParts to my intranet home page.
Recently my site is running too slow.

I'm not sure if its related to WebParts or something else.

Please suggest how can I verify if its an issue with WebParts (any tool to nail it down and point out the culprit)

Comment: have you used components such as grid view or some other components. Are they custom webparts? Due to putting many webparts on one page your page might be taking more time to load.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `SharePoint Developer dashboard` to troubleshoot problems with page components. If your Developer Dashboard doesn’t offer you enough information, you can make use of `SPMonitoredScope` in your code.

**How to enable it ?**

To enable dashboard you need to create the Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application.

Use the below powershell command to create the service application.

```
New-SPUsageApplication -Name "Health and Usage Application" -DatabaseName "SP2013_Health_and_Logging_Database".
```

Once you run the above command it will create the service application with the name Health and Usage Application and the respective database.

Once you have created the service application you have to enable the dashboard.

In the previous versions we use to get three options ON/OFF/OnDemand settings for the dashboard.

Now in this version you will get only two options ON/OFF.

To enable the dashboard, we will use ON setting and use the below powershell command.

```
$svc = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$dds = $svc.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$dds.DisplayLevel = "On"
$dds.Update()
```

After executing the above powershell command open your site on top right hand side of your site, you can see an icon to launch Developer Dashboard.

Please refer [this link](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2013.html#gallery[pageGallery]/0/) for more information.

Comment: @Jason... Is this working for you?

Comment: Is given information helps you to understand the resolution for your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any specific tool for that.

Just remove the webparts one by one until you see the performance rise.

If it never does, the performance problems are likely somewhere else

Comment: To continue Roberts answer, if the performance does not increase you can try and download Teleriks Fiddler and determine how many round trips between the browser and Sp is required.  If this is an Intranet the authentication should be quick.  But on some browsers if the SP site is not   recognized as a local, the browser and server will do more security checks than is needed and slow down perceived performance.

Answer (score 3):

I just kept more than 5 WebParts on my page but the loading time difference between page without WebPart and page with WebPart is of max 2-3 seconds. For more detailing i would like to say that i kept OOTB WebParts.

And your question will not have any specific answer as the scope of answer is too wide. Still i am listing some of the thing which you must verify once.

- Remove all the WebParts and check the loading time
- Add 1 WebPart and check the loading time (try to calculate the difference between loading times)
- Similarly do by keeping all the WebParts
- In addition of this check whether your WebPart is having any complex query for receiving the data.
- If you are using any list WebPart then the size of list (number of records in list) will also matter in loading of page

This are very few option i suggested. Moreover you can also go for some of the free tool which gives the details about loading time of web pages.

And please refer this link once [Performance for sharepoint](https://web.archive.org/web/20161202154037/http://apmblog.dynatrace.com:80/2013/03/12/net-and-sharepoint-performance-dont-let-default-settings-ruin-your-end-user-experience).

I hope it will help you to figure out your loading issue. Let me know whether it helped or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are few more things which you can do to improve performance:

1) Avoid giving reference of plugin files in each web part(ex bootstrap.css, jquery.min.js etc.), 
 instead give references of such files in the master page itself and with the help of javascript append those references in the iframe of web parts.

2) Open audit option in console, find unused css, javascript references which are not used.

Answer (score 0):

noticed people are answering based off the web parts being the issue but 5 web parts on a page is not a lot at all.

few things to note.

is it a live (365) or on-premise server..... is it a live or dev server?

the second part related to the hardware. What is your specs like ram, topology etc.

once the above is answered the next part is the web parts(If its truly effecting the page with a simple test).

Don't remove them as there is no need. Use fiddler to see what is going on with the http requests.

also Create a new page and add the web part one at a time to see the loading times.

is the web parts out of the box or did you develop them? what are they doing... are they getting data from lists and if so how big is the dataset?

need these questions answering to get the right idea of what is causing the issue be it software or a hardware constraint or bad coding.

Comment: Who said the number of webparts is the problem? We are answering based on the fact that user added webparts, then the site went slow. So it is rather possible any one of the webparts are having performance issues (bad code, large amounts of data to process etc.). As you yourself is also noting :)

Comment: yes but 5 webparts shouldnt be an issue on a page tbh. hence why i was surprised no one was wondering what the specs of his environment is. Could be very low spec and when adding ootb web parts that are standard to the page it cant handle the worker process. yes i did note it aswell who couldnt :) . could be bad programming ;) or bad hardware specs

Comment: Ali,

ONPREM - SPS2013 - Production Server.

Will test by adding one by one and update soon.

webpart OOTB and fetching data from Lists.

Hardware is good,as the performance monitor doesnt show any signs of system performance.

Comment: I`ve removed all 05 webparts and added them again one by one, however the page loading still remains from the first webpart addition. Later tried adding another webpart (OOTB) as the first on the page and tested, still the page loading is slow. 

Any further suggestions on tools to check any errors or reasons for page loading testing?